# How to use Corecrypto kernel module on mac/ios

Tags: ios, encryption

I know that Corecrypto kernel module received a FIPS 140 vaulidation, but I can't find any document for this module.
My questions is: how can I leverge this crypto module? For example, is there any API exposed so that I can use it to do AES encryption?

Is it a replacement of CommonCrypto library, or totally different thing?

Comment: There is a "fed-talk" [Arclive](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/fed-talk/2013/Feb/msg00003.html) that addresses this. Essentially "Corecrypto" is used by CommonCrypto. An app needs to restrict itself to use of the "FIPS 140-2 Approved Algorithms". See [Apple iOS CoreCrypto Kernel Module](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140sp/140sp1944.pdf). If your app uses other algorithms such as OPenSSL or Blowfish it can not claim FIPS-140-2 compliance.

Comment: I just noticed, you posted your question to Apple in the wrong place, you need to post to the developer forum at: https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios/core/security